# Discord Js - Different Lines

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm sure the answer is simple but how would I make this:

```
message.channel.send("Suggestions By:", `${message.author}`
message.channel.send("Suggestion:", suggestion);
```

Into one line, I've tried:

```
message.channel.send("Suggestions By:", `${message.author}` /n "Suggestion:", suggestion);
```

And that doesn't work clearly, it's really meant for if I don't have to call anything. Would appreciate the help, Thanks :)

Comment: Try putting `\n` inside of quotation marks

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is confusing. If you trying to concatenate a string (to send it all as one) you should do this instead:

```
message.channel.send(`Suggestion By: ${message.author}\nSuggestion: ${suggestion}`);
```

This way it will concatenate the string into one and send the message to the channel.
If you want to concatenate the string the old way you can also do it like this:

```
message.channel.send("Suggestion By: " + message.author + "\nSuggestion: " + suggestion);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a backslash (“\”) instead of a fowardslash.

Comment: Nope, it says that's a "unexpected token". It doesn't work either.

Comment: Add the backslash inside quotes.

Comment: I have
`message.channel.send("Suggestions By:", `${message.author})` "/n" ("Suggestion:", suggestion);`
Still doesn't work.

Comment: That’s a fowardslash.

Comment: Heck, yeah whoops. It still doesn't work with a backslash, I've tried both.

Comment: Your method of writing the code would not be preferred by me.